# How to set a title for X-axis and Y-axis in line chart using Charts Framework in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts

I am configuring Line Chart using Charts framework. I have done my research but couldn't find relevant information as to how to set the title for X and Y axes(marked by red rectangle) as shown in the attached image.

[Chart Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWhWr.png)

Comment: Which chart framework u use?

Comment: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be something like this code:

```
let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Visitor count")
```

The "label" parameter is the title.

Comment: I believe the parameter "label" represents Legend in the graph and not the title of the axes.